# android java - How do you do to set visibility false and true in a Polyline on Google Maps api?

Tags: java, android, maps

Hello World im new programming...

i am creating a trip app...

i have an Activity with LinearLayout that contains 6 ImageButtons , and after the LinearLayout there is a FrameLayout with Google Maps; in the logical part there are 6 Polylines, all of these Polylines have .visible(false)

i would like click in 1 ImageButton and get 1 Polyline set .visible(true) and if i click again the ImageButton set that Polyline .visible(false)

thanks in advance!!!

I use this code to my Zoom Buttons but i do not know how configure them to change visibility on polylines...

```
public class TransBus extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

ImageButton busBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_trans_bus);

    //Hooks
    busBtn = findViewById(R.id.bus1);

     busBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) { visibilityOn(); }
    });

    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, supportMapFragment).commit();
    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}

public void visibilityOn() {?
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setVisibility() method of polylineOptions defined in the [android sdk](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/polygon-tutorial).

You can change the visibility by calling this code on the polyline object

```
 polyline.setVisibility(false)
```

if you want to check out other methods you can check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/maps/model/Polyline)

Comment: thanks, but how i set the function for the  buttons to interact with each Polyline? how i call an specific polyline get visible?

Comment: i dont understand. do you mean on the click of a button you want to make it false

Comment: Yes Samuel, thats what i want, i was trying but i dont get the correct form, i would like some help, or reference to study thanks in advance